# C# multiple replace works slow, any faster idea?

Tags: c#, html, replace, special-characters

```
return mystring.replace(/&/g, "&amp;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;")  
      .replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/"/g, "&quot;");
```

The above is my code, and I guess since it tracks the string 4 times, it makes it slower. Is there any other way (method prefered) to replace those special characters in only one loop? Well I can do it with a for loop and checking char by char, but it is not smthing I would like to.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HtmlEncode and HtmlDecode should work. I'll add more info in a minute.

---

Here's a link to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3te6wfz.aspx).

Of course - i'm assuming that's what you are trying to achieve and other kind of string replacements are not necessary.

---

Forgot to add - i haven't done any performance tests. And yet - it`s supposed to work faster.

Comment: As Arnis says, if you're just trying to encode HTML into entities you should use HtmlEncode.